# ubuntu 12.04 blank screen

Tags: 12.04, screen

Ok so a year later I am asking again how do i update this computer everytime i update to 12.04 i have to reinstall at like 9.04 or what ever and then update works good till 12.04 never fails everytime blank screen why is this if you tell me the stuff to do I will run what ever so you can look at my syestem and tell me why ? last time I asked this question It was a dead duck but the computer is running now and update works right up to 12.04 then blank screen ps I think that the person who posts the question should close it

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!